# creating submenu in css

Tags: html, css, submenu

I know this question is asked so many times but I'm getting a problem while creating an sub menu in CSS. I'm new to CSS and don't know so much about it but after trying to Google so much I tried an small menu using CSS, everything works fine but only sub menu doesn't comes in stacked way.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Example 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Example 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Example 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Example 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Example 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

CSS

```
ul
{
    list-style:none;
    padding: 8px 15px;
}
li
{
    float:left;
}
li a
{
    background: #CCC;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
li ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#999;
}
li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;
}
li ul a
{
    display:block;
}
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vighanesh/r52sX/) link. Please tell me where do I making mistake.

Comment: so do you want the submenu items to be displayed vertically ?

Comment: yes but it shows in horizontally @Bobby5193

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What's Going On

Your top level `li`s are floated, which makes sense. If you want the submenu to stack, you just need to get sub `li`s to `float:none`.

### CODE

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r52sX/1/)

```
li ul li {
    float:none;
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your code

```
ul ul li {
    float:none;
    display: block;
}
```

The problem is that at the first time you are setting to the li `{float:left}` and it effects to the next li in your sub menu. so you only need `float:none`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the `li { float:left; }` style is applied to all `li` elements, including nested ones.  You need to override the styles applied to the nested submenu items, with something like `ul li ul li { float: none; }`.

Finally, it may be better to use classes to apply styles rather than applying them directly to elements.  This is the approach that Twitter Bootstrap takes for its [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).  This may look like the following:

`<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Example 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Example 3</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Example 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Example 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Example 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>`

`ul.menu > li {
  float: left;
}`

In this case the style is applied only to the children of `.menu`, instead of all `li` elements.  This is super useful if you use lists later on in your page.

Comment: +1 for answer and going beyond with class idea, and Bootstrap example.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li {float:left}
ul li ul li {display:block;clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the items in the submenu to display vertically is to add a class to the submenu  and target the li in order to remove the float property with `float:none;`

Here's an updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/r52sX/2/

I've added the class instead of just scoping for the li elements in order to make this applicable if you have multiple submenu lists

Answer (score 0):

**The float property specifies whether or not a box (an element) should float.**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QZLfL/1/)**

**CSS**

```
li ul li {
    float: none;
}
```